# Controlling Android app emulator with Mac's keyboard?

Tags: android, controls, emulation, volume

I'm trying to overcome a challenge of controlling my soundbar volume from my Mac. No volume sync alternatives are available, I tried them all so all the hope lays within this idea:

My soundbar volume can be controlled from an android/iOS app connected to the soundbar over wifi.
My plan is to have a android app simulator running and somehow bind volume keys to control the volume slider in the app. It sounds difficult so before I start trying I wanted to ask whether those things are at all possible:

- Connecting the soundbar using app running on the android simulator via Wifi
- Binding volume keys on my Mac to control the touch input of the android app emulator

*If you have other ideas like using an actual phone and controlling its touch input I'm open to suggestion as I have some android phones laying around*

Comment: i don't think you have the correct community here...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the best solution for your problem. Maybe try to find out how the soundbar receives commands and try to emulate those with an API.